# How to dynamically create an instance of tinymce using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

How to dynamically create an instance of tinymce using javascript? This is my code so far:

javascript:

```
$(function()
{   

    $("#onesnippet").click(function()
    {
        alert("One Snippet");

        var idiv = document.getElementById('translations');
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.id = 10;
        idiv.appendChild(newdiv);

        var latestdiv = document.createElement('div')
        latestdiv.id = 4;
        newdiv.appendChild(latestdiv);

        var textarea1 = document.createElement('textarea');
        textarea1.id = "mceEditor3";
        textarea1.className = "mceEditor";

        latestdiv.appendChild(textarea1);
    });

});
```

php file to include tinymce :

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({mode : "specific_textareas", element : "mceEditor,mceEditor1,mceEditor2,mceEditor3", editor_selector : "mceEditor"});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You finish your code, and then add editor initiate code.

```
$(function()
{   

    $("#onesnippet").click(function()
    {
        alert("One Snippet");

        var idiv = document.getElementById('translations');
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.id = 10;
        idiv.appendChild(newdiv);

        var latestdiv = document.createElement('div')
        latestdiv.id = 4;
        newdiv.appendChild(latestdiv);

        var textarea1 = document.createElement('textarea');
        textarea1.id = "mceEditor3";
        textarea1.className = "mceEditor";

        latestdiv.appendChild(textarea1);

        tinymce.init({mode : "specific_textareas", element : "mceEditor,mceEditor1,mceEditor2,mceEditor3", editor_selector : "mceEditor"});

    });

});
```